# ReactJS absolute url images not showing in production build

Tags: reactjs, html-base

**Scenario**

- My ReactJS app uses images from `public/images` which becomes `build/images` on a production build.
- This project lives in a few different places on the web so I am using a site-based absolute path structure for items like images (eg leading slash '/images/my-image.png') as my router's base name changes depending on where the app instance is going to live *eg "www.location1.com" and "www.another.com/location/2"*
- All images work in development, on production I have to remove the leading "/" for images to work.
- The biggest issue is that I'm loading in json that contains `<img>` tags using absolute URL's so my current solution of removing leading slashes is very hacky.

**Current Attempts**

- using a `<base>` inside the index.html's head tag (seems to help)
- using v4 Router `basename=` (doesn't seem to help)
- javascript function to strip '/' as needed (works but is hacky)
- `.htaccess` file in folder (seems to help)
- `package.json` set homepage / homepage-web (doesn't seem to help)

**Question**

How can I make sure that both my development environment and production environment display images the same? So far it seems like `<head><base>` and `.htaccess` are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- add .env variable `REACT_APP_BASENAME=/base/for/site`
- using html base of `<base href="%REACT_APP_BASENAME%"/>`
- strictly using relative img urls eg `<img src="some/where/relative.img>`
- making sure react router `basename` also reads from .env variable REACT_APP_BASENAME

For mobile devices I wrote a script that changes the base href to "." and then I have an `onDeviceReady` function that rewrites the `document.head.base` to use the app folder path useing `window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory` - the "file" (for folder name) and "device" (for `onDeviceReady`) cordova plugins will be needed.